# Instantiate Java Scanner in class or method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, instantiation

I have created a class to read user input. I am using scanner to get user input and sanitize it. When using scanner object, it struck me with a question which of these 2 approaches will be best practice:

- To create a Scanner reference in a class & instantiate it -> use it in each method

  ```
  private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  public int readInt() {

     int input = sc.nextInt();           
     // some code to restrict input to integers only
     return input;    

  }

  public int readDouble() {

     int double = sc.nextDouble();
     // some code to restrict input to double only
     return input;    

  }
  ```
- To create a Scanner reference a class -> instantiate it in each method -> use it in each method

  ```
  private Scanner;

  public int readInt() {

     sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     int input = sc.nextInt();           
     // some code to restrict input to integers only
     return input;    

  }

  public int readDouble() {

     sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     int double = sc.nextDouble();
     // some code to restrict input to double only
     return input;    

  }
  ```

  Imagine a scenario where an object of this class will be created in another class, and readInt() or readDouble() will be called several times. In that case which of the 2 above mentioned approaches will be more practical from security and memory standpoint?

Or as one of the comments suggested none of the above are practical and the best way will be to pass a scanner object as a paramter to each of the methods ?

Comment: How about creating the scanner in the method that wants to read, and pass it as argument to the methods? That would be the best option, IMO.

Comment: Be careful with `nextInt` followed by `nextLine` in the first case.. (if you have `readLine` in your code)

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. That is a good option indeed. However for more elegant code I wanted to take care of all Scanner objects in this class and import it only here.

Answer (score 2):

this problem is so good,and i want to declare my opinion.
on the one hand,in the model of Single-threaded ,the method of creating Scanner reference in class is equal to the method of instantiating  it.
on the other hand,in the model of Multithreading，the method of creating Scanner refenence
in class may not get the correct answer.